# How to print HTML elements as pages in Safari?

Tags: html, css, printing, safari

The following code should result in each `div` being printed as a separate page. Each `div` is set to a `width` and `height` of `100%`. This HTML page prints as three pages in **all browsers other than Safari 5.6.1**. How can I fix it in Safari?

Please copy the following code to new file and test it:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: auto;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    input {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="background-color:red; position:  relative; width:100%;height:100%;">
    <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 1.2%;left:1.2%">
    <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 6.4%;left:1.3%">
    <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 10.4%;left:1.3%">
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:green; position:  relative; width:100%;height:100%;">
    <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 1.2%;left:1.2%">
    <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 6.4%;left:1.3%">
    <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 10.4%;left:1.3%">
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:red; position:  relative; width:100%;height:100%;">
    <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 1.2%;left:1.2%">
    <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 6.4%;left:1.3%">
    <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 10.4%;left:1.3%">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you give `position:absolute;` on inputs, what do you want exactly?

Comment: Did you try setting the width and height of the DIVs to the same size as paper? I suggest using a media query: `@media print { div { width: 8in; height: 11in } }`. You may need to play with the values a little.

Comment: I cannot imagine the market share of people trying to print using safari 5.6.1 justifying the bits added to your file size to create this compatibility :/

Answer (score 5):

### Solution

You should consider using `page-break-after`. You can force a page break for each of the `div`'s in your example by simply adding `page-break-after: always;` to your `div` styling.

### Compatibility

If you check `page-break-after` on the [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=page-break-before) website, **98.26%** of browsers support it. This includes **Safari 5.x** and all other versions of Safari.

### Your HTML

If you wanted to add the `page-break-after` attribute inline, you'd use the following code:

```
<div style="background-color:red; position: relative; width:100%; height:100%; page-break-after: always;">
  <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 1.2%;left:1.2%">
  <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 6.4%;left:1.3%">
  <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 10.4%;left:1.3%">
</div>
<div style="background-color:green; position: relative; width:100%; height:100%; page-break-after: always;">
  <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 1.2%;left:1.2%">
  <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 6.4%;left:1.3%">
  <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 10.4%;left:1.3%">
</div>
<div style="background-color:red; position: relative; width:100%; height:100%; page-break-after: always;">
  <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 1.2%;left:1.2%">
  <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 6.4%;left:1.3%">
  <input type="text" style="width:5%; height:1.2%; border:1px solid; position:absolute; top: 10.4%;left:1.3%">
</div>
```

### Your Code

If you wanted to only add `page-break-after` to your `div`'s when users print, you would use the `@media print` **CSS** query like so:

```
@media print {
  div {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

It's worth noting, that `@media` queries can not be used in inline styling, you would have to add it to a **CSS** file, or between `<style>` tags.

### Updated Answer

Since **Safari 5.x** is still printing five page instead of three like the others, try adding the following code to your **HTML**:

```
<style>
  @media print {
    div {
      width: auto !important; /* 100% Might be breaking your current code. */
      height: auto !important; /* 100% Might be breaking your current code. */
      page-break-after: always;
    }
  }
</style>
```

It might be possible that Safari is recognizing the value as being higher than 100%, causing one `div` to print into multiple pages.

If the above code doesn't work, try adding `height: 50px !important;` to the `div` styling and report back with the results. Ex. What colors are showing up on what pages?

### Check Safari

Let's try some custom code to see if this is a bug for **Safari 5.x**. We are going to create three `div` elements, with the `page-break-after` property. Nothing more.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <div style="page-break-after: always;">Page 1</div>
   <div style="page-break-after: always;">Page 2</div>
   <div style="page-break-after: always;">Page 3</div>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Paste that into a new blank HTML document, then save it and try printing. Does Safari still want to print 5 pages? If so, that's a bug with Safari.

If that only prints on 3 pages, try removing `position:absolute` from the `input`'s in your code. If that doesn't fix it, slowly just rebuild your page from scratch to see what code is causing it to split into 5 pages.

### More Info

> You can learn more about the `page-break` properties by visiting [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp) or [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/).

Comment: with `page-break` style too it prints into five pages all the other browser it print on three pages

Comment: @azad Try seeing my **Updated Answer** section to see if that fixes the problem. If not, try my `50px` code and report back.

Comment: No it doesn't solve the problem thank you for your effort sir,

Comment: color is no problem, In my above code each div should be printed on each page altogether three pages

Comment: colors are not printed on pages

Comment: Did you try my **Check Safari** section to make sure it's not just a bug with Safari 5.x?

Answer (score 0):

Safari 5.1 is simply too old, and it is impossible to find one to install now, not to mention testing on it. Official support stopped in 2013 too.([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history))

I suggest you may try media query on printing. Something like:

```
@media print {
    div {
        position:  relative;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
}
```